# what are differences Dependency Injection, Inversion of Control, or Service Locator?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

What are the differences between 
- Dependency Injection (DI)
- Inversion of Control (Ioc)
- Service Locator?

And also Why do you need and use Unity when developing WebAPIs ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control):

> > Inversion of Control, or IoC, is an abstract principle describing an aspect of some software architecture designs in which the flow of control of a system is inverted in comparison to procedural programming

Basically **Inversion of Control** is a **Design Pattern** and **Dependency Injection** and **Service Locator** are methodologies to achieve Inversion of Control.

[Read this article for getting clear understanding](http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/)

Also read this [MSDN article on Inversion of Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx) and [Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx)

You should also read [this good CodeProject article on Inversion of Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29271/Design-pattern-Inversion-of-control-and-Dependency)

Comment: And probably http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ as well

Comment: in thie first article i gave he explains about Service locator that it is not preffered much